# How to save data locally in the Android Studio webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I saw that there are many questions on the subject on the forum, but I do not think that one applies to my case. I'm developing an app through the WebView of Android Studio that lets you shop online. The application must collect the name, phone, and client address at startup. Then, write the data locally to use them as reference to save later on in the database. I used this command to save the data locally:

> localStorage.setItem('name', 'John');

But it is not compatible with Android Studio, so I added it to MainActivity:

> settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

Even so, I could not save the data locally. Is there any way to save and extract the data locally in this case?

The code of MainActivity is:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
String databasePath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webView = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Get rid of the android title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.main_webview);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

    //Enable Javascript
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //Enable DOM storage, and tell Android where to save the Database
        settings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/");
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            /** Called when the database exceeds it's maximum size **/
            @Override
            public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize, long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {
            //Double the estimated size of the Database
               quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 2);
        } 
        });
    }
}
```